# Local new object or global static object

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Suppose I have a wcf service

```
public class DataService : IDataService
```

Suppose
I need a `JavaScriptSerializer` object to be used in  every method in my service to serialise my object to json string and to send it back to caller
(by wrapping by another class)

Should I do

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

in every method in the class, or can I just have

```
private static JavaScriptSerializer serializer = newJavaScriptSerializer();`
```

at the top of my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use that variable very frequently, it is an option to make it `static`. The memory pressure of that single variable is negligible, while it may have a positive performance impact. But there are caveats to consider too.

One concern could be thread safety, if you intend to use it in a multi-threaded environment. The documentation doesn't state it is thread-safe, so we have to assume it isn't thread safe.

Another consideration when using WCF (or any ASP.NET hosted service), is that `static` is shared across all instances. Although unlikely in this case, but there is a possibility that your `static` will expose information to other sessions than you intend to.

**Don't use `static` in WCF unless you are very, very sure it is safe to do so.**

Comment: I don't think `JavascriptSerializer` is thread safe. There's also no real downside of making an object that doesn't have state (in other words: if it was supposed to be thread-safe, it probably wouldn't have had state - which means construction negligable). If you want to pursue static, do it properly with a threadstatic -- otherwise, I'd strongly discourage this.

Comment: @atlaste I strongly recommend to avoid `static` too, as in my answer.

Comment: [...] "there is no harm in keeping it in a static." -- There is most definitely harm.

Comment: @atlaste: Did you read the disclaimer too :) . I got your point, will update.

Comment: Hrm. You have to understand: I'm making such a point because I've seen a lot of enterprise software using similar constructs to do WCF calls, SQL calls, etc. The effects are crashes, data bleeding through, undefined behavior, etc. In fact, I believe it's the most common error made in enterprise software (!) Therefore I strongly urge everyone to state that **It's Just Plain Wrong**. :-) If there is a performance hit, it's there because state is initialized - which means it's probably there for a reason.

Comment: -1 this is actually a dangerous suggestion. most web apps are multi-threaded, as most things that use JSON. the documentation for JavaScriptSerializer  states that it's **NOT** thread safe. So having it static may lead to strange and unreproducible racing condition bugs...

Comment: @PatrickHofman i wrote the comment before you edited. I think it's a bad idea having these sort of classes in any shared state, or `static` state. it's dangerous, and the impact on performance is usually negligible. sometimes it can even harm performance (shared memory between threads). All this applies not only to multi-threading (it can cause regular bugs too), and certainly not only to WCF. So I believe the general sentiment should be discouragement.

Answer (score 2):

Using `static` variables in a web service has some side effects that you need to be aware of.

Considering the negligable overhead of [creating a new serializer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptSerializer.cs,d0a9bc29c74591f9) compared to actually *using* it once, I'd say you should have a local variable. The cost is minimal and you gain a lot of safety against strange multithreading errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally never use static like this - creating a new serializer is negligable , and so it seems you're trying to do micro optimization, something you should  avoid.

Instead you could 'constructor inject' instances of JavaScriptSerializer (preferably using an interface), maybe (but not absolutely required) by using a IoC container like [StructureMap](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/) or Unity.

Like this your serializer can easily be mocked and replaced, and you create modular and testable code, and you can easily determine the lifetime of your instances.

```
 public class DataService : IDataService
 {
      private readonly IJavaScriptSerializer  _serializer;

      public DataService(IJavaScriptSerializer serializer)
      {
          _serializer = serializer;
      }
 }
```

In this case this means that you write an interface IJavaScriptSerializer, and a custom implementation of it that internally uses JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: Interfaces are nice for business objects, they're usually less crucial for platform object...

Comment: Main point is to be able to mock it and not have a strong dependency on it in unit tests.

Comment: With business objects it makes sense, here to be able to mock it, you will need and entire wrapper class, and mocking it will probably give you nothing. you would be better off just using it in the unit tests... the general idea is good though...

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer  is .net built in class, there is no IJavaScriptSerializer

Answer (score 1):

**New is always better.**

Always, especially when in doubt, it is better to create a new instance of a helper class just for your specific operation. It costs almost nothing, and its the easiest safest way to do it.

Only if you are certain that the helper/service/whatever class your is immutable or you thoroughly understand its behavior **and** you really need it to be shared, only then you should share it between operations.

Also, you should probably receive all the helper/service/etc objects you need in the constructor, and you would be better to use a [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to handle all this.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, this is why you should read the entire answer and not just the first sentence.